# AEM 6.4 overlaying internal area components/files which is under /libs

Tags: content-management-system, upgrade, aem, jcr

We are migrating from aem 6.2 to aem 6.4, I am facing this problem, we have overlayed few components in 6.2 now that components are under internal area in 6.4. 
According to aem 6.4 we should not overlay aem internal components.
I want to keep this overlay function in 6.4 as well, Is there anyway to do it. 
Suggest something please.
Thanks,
Surya

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done it, but I think if you MUST change the functionality of an Internal component, you will need to duplicate it so that it has no association with the original component. So if it was `cq/foundation/components/123` you would copy it and make it `myapp/components/123`.

Since you're doing an upgrade, you could then use something like [ResourceType Updater](https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-tools/features/csv-resource-type-updater/index.html) to update all of the old resource types to the new resource type.

Comment: Bearcherian Thanks for the reply :) , for component you are asking me to recreate a new component i will try this. is there is anyway to modify files in internal area.